# apache build issues

Tags: c++, apache, apache2

i have been seeing these errors whilst attempting to build, i am attempting to build a standalone executable but with little success, can someone please advise?

```
 undefined reference to `ap_get_server_name'
 undefined reference to `apreq_handle_apache2'
 undefined reference to `ap_hook_child_init'
 undefined reference to `ap_get_server_port'
 undefined reference to `ap_hook_handler'
 undefined reference to `ap_hook_post_config'
 undefined reference to `ap_log_error_'
 undefined reference to `ap_get_brigade'
 undefined reference to `ap_rwrite'
```

This is mostly what my makefile contains:

```
all:libBidRequestTest.so InitTest

libBidRequestTest.so:
    g++ -g -fPIC -shared $(OBJS) -lxerces-c -lrtbshm -lb64  -lapr-1  -laprutil-1   -lapreq2 -lpcre -lrt -lpthread -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lzdb -lOpenRTBv1 -lOpenRTBv2 -lAdX -lRubicon -lIP2Location -L$(PREFIX)/lib  -L../common/shm -L../common/base64 -o /usr/local/infinity/lib/$@

InitTest: InitTest.cpp
    g++ -g -fPIC $< $(APXS_CFLAGS) $(APXS_CFLAGS_SHLIB) $(INCLUDES) -I$(APXS_INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDES)  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_unit_test_framework -lBidRequestTest -ldl -lboost_system  -L/usr/local/infinity/apache/lib -o $@
```

Comment: Link with the APR libraries for the program too?

Comment: you mean -lapr-1? I did that when building the libBidRequestTest.so